# How do I use ICalculator in ArcEngine?

Tags: esri-arc-engine

I'm trying to calculate value for field from the attribute table of a shapefile using ArcEngine, looking up in EDN & ArcGIS help and I wrote code as below:

```
ICalculator pCalculator = new Calculator();
pCalculator.Field = pField.Name;
string ex = "!POP06!-!POP02!";
pCalculator.Expression = ex;
pCalculator.Calculate();
```

`pField` is the target field I want to update the value, `POP06` & `POP02` are two fields I use to calculate, using `!` for python.

When I run the program VS2010 said "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component". I could tell that ICalcultor haven't set any dependence on attribute table, but I don't know how to do. Also, are there any other problems in my code?

Comment: @Erica Thanks for your edit！

Comment: You're welcome. Hope you get some good answers :)